# Vis.js vertical node position with hierarchical layout

Tags: vis.js

As seen using this codepen https://codepen.io/fourlightson/pen/RwNxVry, the nodes on level **6** are offset to the right hand side for some reason. At the moment i'm using only the most simple options:

```
  var options = {
    layout: {
    hierarchical: {
      direction: "UD",
      sortMethod: "directed",
      nodeSpacing: 400  
    }
  }
  };
```

[image]

I have failed to find a configuration that positions the highlighted nodes more centrally to adhere to a more top down, vertical appearance.

Can anyone help with a configuration change that would help position the level 6 nodes so they are aligned vertically with the level 1 nodes for example ?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

turns out if i reduce the `nodeSpacing:` value it does what i want. I used `nodeSpacing: 1`.